# Unable to import and use org.apache.commons even though it is added to classpath

Tags: java, import

As the title suggests I am unable to use the apache commons library in Jgrasp even though the jar file has been added to my classpath. Attached are screenshots. This really doesn't make any sense to me as I've followed all the advice i could find an nothing seemed to have worked.

Classpath: [Classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkQaP.png)

imports: [My imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laF0m.png)

Output: [Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgFOg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't import a package tree, only an individual package.

In this case, I assume you mean to import org.apache.commons.io.* .